# const prefix on output pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have this piece of C++ code that I felt a little confusing:

```
int foo (const char* &bar)
```

In this case, if I want to write to the bar pointer as:

```
bar = ...
```

It is ok. So How should I understand this `const`. How a const pointer different from a pointer points to a const value?

Comment: This code contains a reference, so I've removed the "C" tag.

Comment: `bar` is a reference to a pointer to const memory

Comment: @Dave oops right. A bit of const dyslexia...

Comment: And this is why contrary to tradition, `const` should always be written on the *right* side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` applies to whatever is to the left of it, unless there is nothing to the left of it, in which case it applies to whatever is to the right of it.  That means in your case, `bar` is a reference to a pointer to a `const char`.  `bar` itself is not constant and can be modified.

If you change `bar` to be `char * const &bar`, that is - a reference to a constant pointer to `char`, you won't be able to make that assignment.  Example:

```
int foo (char * const &bar)
{
    bar = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

and trying to compile it:

```
$ clang++ -c -o example.o example.cpp
example.cpp:3:9: error: read-only variable is not assignable
    bar = 0;
    ~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [example.o] Error 1
```

You can use [`cdecl`/`c++decl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl) to parse these declarations if they're causing you trouble:

```
$ c++decl
Type `help' or `?' for help
c++decl> explain const char * &bar
declare bar as reference to pointer to const char
c++decl> explain char * const &bar
declare bar as reference to const pointer to char
```

Answer (score 4):

If a pointer is `const`, you aren't allowed to assign to the pointer. E.g.

```
char * const bar;

bar = ...; // This is invalid
*bar = ...; // This is OK
bar[i] = ...; // This is OK
```

If a pointer points to a `const` value, you aren't allowed to assign to what the pointer points to. E.g.

```
const char *bar;

bar = ...; // This is OK
*bar = ...; // This is invalid
bar[i] = ...; // This is invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll add some examples. Maybe this will make it clearer to some people:

The spaces make no difference in any of these, so I'm putting them everywhere to avoid ambiguity.

---

```
const char * & bar
```

`bar` is *not* const, `*bar` is const (this also means `bar[0]`, etc.). If you change `bar`, it will now point to new memory (like a new array), but the old data will remain unchanged.

---

```
char const * & bar
```

same as above.

---

```
char * const & bar
```

`bar` is now const (you can't change it to point to different memory), but the memory itself (`*bar`) can be changed

---

```
const char * const & bar
```

`bar` and `*bar` are both const. You can't change anything.

---

```
char * & const bar
```

This is an error.

---

The code you found is using the first form to (in effect) return a `const char` array. The caller isn't allowed to pass a `char*`; it must be a `const char*`, so unless the caller casts away the const-ness (which is a bad thing to do), they won't be modifying the memory. This means the function can safely return a pointer to internal data, knowing that it won't be modified.